# create 2d occupancy grid map by laser data

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want  to create 2d occupancy grid map manually without using slam packages help me please with tutorials  or documentation to learn how i can do that
thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286221/create-2d-occupancy-grid-map--by-laser-data/) by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-03-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2018-03-26**:
What do you mean by "without slam packages"? Are you trying to implement your own SLAM, or are you just wanting to make a very primitive map?

**Comment by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on 2018-03-26**:
i want just to create a simple map ( local map )for navigation to implement some  demonstration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
As long as the accurate poses of the robot are not known, you are not able to build a consistent map without using a SLAM  framework. Because all the measurements and controls (Range and odometry) are inherently uncertain. you can build a local map without changing the robot pose or a barely accurate map with small movements. Use follwing python codes to get started.

build local map using `localmap.py`

```
import bresenham
from math import sin, cos, pi,tan, atan2,log
import math
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import tf
import rospy
import numpy as np
from geometry_msgs.msg import TransformStamped
from geometry_msgs.msg import PointStamped

class localmap:
    def __init__(self, height, width, resolution,morigin):
        self.height=height
        self.width=width
        self.resolution=resolution
        self.punknown=-1.0
        self.localmap=[self.punknown]*int(self.width/self.resolution)*int(self.height/self.resolution)
        self.logodds=[0.0]*int(self.width/self.resolution)*int(self.height/self.resolution)
        self.origin=int(math.ceil(morigin[0]/resolution))+int(math.ceil(width/resolution)*math.ceil(morigin[1]/resolution))
        self.pfree=log(0.3/0.7)
        self.pocc=log(0.9/0.1)
        self.prior=log(0.5/0.5)
        self.max_logodd=100.0
        self.max_logodd_belief=10.0
        self.max_scan_range=1.0
        self.map_origin=morigin
        

                
    def updatemap(self,scandata,angle_min,angle_max,angle_increment,range_min,range_max,pose):
        
        robot_origin=int(pose[0])+int(math.ceil(self.width/self.resolution)*pose[1])
        centreray=len(scandata)/2+1
        for i in range(len(scandata)):
            if not math.isnan(scandata[i]):
                beta=(i-centreray)*angle_increment
                px=int(float(scandata[i])*cos(beta-pose[2])/self.resolution)
                py=int(float(scandata[i])*sin(beta-pose[2])/self.resolution)

                l = bresenham.bresenham([0,0],[px,py])
                for j in range(len(l.path)):                    
                    lpx=self.map_origin[0]+pose[0]+l.path[j][0]*self.resolution
                    lpy=self.map_origin[1]+pose[1]+l.path[j][1]*self.resolution
                    
                    if (0<=lpx<self.width and 0<=lpy<self.height):
                        index=self.origin+int(l.path[j][0]+math.ceil(self.width/self.resolution)*l.path[j][1])
                        if scandata[i]<self.max_scan_range*range_max:
                            if(j<len(l.path)-1):self.logodds[index]+=self.pfree
                            else:self.logodds[index]+=self.pocc
                        else:self.logodds[index]+=self.pfree                        
                        if self.logodds[index]>self.max_logodd:self.logodds[index]=self.max_logodd
                        elif self.logodds[index]<-self.max_logodd:self.logodds[index]=-self.max_logodd
                        if self.logodds[index]>self.max_logodd_belief:self.localmap[index]=100
                        else:self.localmap[index]=0 
                        self.localmap[self.origin]=100.0
```

use main function `main.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import roslib
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
from std_msgs.msg import String
from nav_msgs.msg import OccupancyGrid
import tf
import math
from math import sin, cos, pi,tan, atan2
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

from localmap import localmap
pose=[0.0,0.0,0.0]
#***********************************************************************
def handle_robot_pose(parent, child, pose):
    br = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
    br.sendTransform((pose[0], pose[1], 0), tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, pose[2]), rospy.Time.now(), child,parent)
    
#***********************************************************************
def odometryCb(msg):
    global pose
    x=msg.pose.pose.position.x
    y=msg.pose.pose.position.y
    q0 = msg.pose.pose.orientation.w
    q1 = msg.pose.pose.orientation.x
    q2 = msg.pose.pose.orientation.y
    q3 = msg.pose.pose.orientation.z
    theta=atan2(2*(q0*q3+q1*q2),1-2*(q2*q2+q3*q3))
    pose=[x,y,theta]
    
#*********************************************************************** 
def scanCb(msg):
    print pose
    py,px=[],[]
    scandata=msg.ranges
    angle_min=msg.angle_min
    angle_max=msg.angle_max
    angle_increment=msg.angle_increment
    range_min=msg.range_min
    range_max=msg.range_max 
    m.updatemap(scandata,angle_min,angle_max,angle_increment,range_min,range_max,pose)
    handle_robot_pose("map", "odom", pose)

#***********************************************************************    
def mappublisher(m,height, width, resolution,morigin):
    msg = OccupancyGrid()
    msg.header.frame_id='map'
    msg.info.resolution = resolution
    msg.info.width      = math.ceil(width/resolution)
    msg.info.height     = math.ceil(height/resolution)
    msg.info.origin.position.x=-morigin[0]
    msg.info.origin.position.y=-morigin[1]
    msg.data=m  
    mappub.publish(msg)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    rospy.init_node('main', anonymous=True) #make node 
    rospy.Subscriber('/odom',Odometry,odometryCb)
    rospy.Subscriber("/scan", LaserScan, scanCb)
    mappub= rospy.Publisher('/map',OccupancyGrid,queue_size=1)
    
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 100hz   
    
    height, width, resolution=10,10,0.05
    morigin=[width/2.0,height/2.0]
    m=localmap(height, width, resolution,morigin)
    
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        mappublisher(m.localmap,height, width, resolution,morigin)
        rate.sleep()
```

Use supplementary script `bresenham.py`

```
class bresenham:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = list(start)
        self.end = list(end)
        self.path = []
        self.toggle=0
        
        if start[0]-end[0]+start[1]-end[1]==0:
            return None
        
        self.steep = abs(self.end[1]-self.start[1]) > abs(self.end[0]-self.start[0])
        
        if self.steep:
            self.start = self.swap(self.start[0],self.start[1])
            self.end = self.swap(self.end[0],self.end[1])
        
        if self.start[0] > self.end[0]:
            self.toggle=1
            #print 'flippin and floppin'
            _x0 = int(self.start[0])
            _x1 = int(self.end[0])
            self.start[0] = _x1
            self.end[0] = _x0
            
            _y0 = int(self.start[1])
            _y1 = int(self.end[1])
            self.start[1] = _y1
            self.end[1] = _y0
        
        dx = self.end[0] - self.start[0]
        dy = abs(self.end[1] - self.start[1])
        error = 0
        derr = dy/float(dx)
        
        ystep = 0
        y = self.start[1]
        
        if self.start[1] < self.end[1]: ystep = 1
        else: ystep = -1
        
        for x in range(self.start[0],self.end[0]+1):
            if self.steep:
                self.path.append((y,x))
            else:
                self.path.append((x,y))
            
            error += derr
            
            if error >= 0.5:
                y += ystep
                error -= 1.0
        
        if self.toggle==1:
            self.path.reverse()
            
    def swap(self,n1,n2):
        return [n2,n1]
```

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on 2018-03-26**:
that is exactly what i am looking for just to create a local map with small movements it s enough for me .  can you help me how i can do that

**Comment by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) on 2018-03-26**:
See the updated answer Good luck!

**Comment by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on 2018-03-26**:
i will start with this script and reply you later
thank you very much

**Comment by [suho0515](https://answers.ros.org/users/40477/suho0515/) on 2019-08-08**:
it is very helpful. thanks!
could you mention that where did you get these code?

**Comment by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) on 2019-08-08**:
this was my own code, I think the original question has been posted a long time ago, Unfortunately, I don't have these codes anymore. Please try this code. This is a simple code with some math.

**Comment by [suho0515](https://answers.ros.org/users/40477/suho0515/) on 2019-08-08**:
Thanks again, i'm gonna try it! can i ask you something? if i understand right,
the "main.py" get "scan data", "odom data" and send these data to localmap function.
after calculating "somthing" in localmap function, finally they publish map data.
so... what "localmap.py" do? just drawing map?
and, is localization or navigation algorithm working in "bresenham.py"?

sorry for too many question, but i really do wanna understand your work well.
if there is paper or article about this algorithms could you mention it?

thanks again Gayan Brahmanage!

**Comment by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) on 2019-08-09**:
You can follow this [tutorial](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/robotics-learning/week-3-introduction-DFay8) to understand the math behind the code

**Comment by [suho0515](https://answers.ros.org/users/40477/suho0515/) on 2019-08-09**:
Thank you very much :)

**Comment by [suho0515](https://answers.ros.org/users/40477/suho0515/) on 2019-08-09**:
i finally worked with this code.

i've changed 3 thing.

1. odometry topic name to the name i'm subscribed in main.py
2. there is inf value in my lidar sensor data. so i changed parsing code in localmap.py.
   line 39, "if not math.isnan(scandata[i]):" to "if not math.isinf(scandata[i]):"
3. in localmap.py line 65, if(j<len(l.path)-1):self.logodds[index]+=self.pfree.
   sometimes the index value over the len(self.logodds)
   so i input "if (index < len(self.logodds)):" before "if scandata[i]<self.max_scan_range*range_max:"

hope you guys get helped with it!